# ERROR ANDROID: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

Tags: java, android, class

I'm trying to send e-mail but i keep getting this error:

> Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
>                                                                           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2088)
>                                                                           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
>                                                                           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
>                                                                           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
>                                                                           at com.tsiw.testeinvite.GMail.sendEmail(GMail.java:77)
>                                                                           at com.tsiw.testeinvite.SendMailTask.doInBackground(SendMailTask.java:40)
>                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Here's my code:

**Gmail.java**

```
package com.tsiw.testeinvite;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class GMail {
final String emailPort = "465";// gmail's smtp port
final String smtpAuth = "true";
final String starttls = "true";
final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
// final String fromUser = "REMOVED";
// final String fromUserEmailPassword = "REMOVED";

String fromEmail;
String fromPassword;
List<String> toEmailList;
String emailSubject;
String emailBody;

Properties emailProperties;
Session mailSession;
MimeMessage emailMessage;

public GMail() {

}

public GMail(String fromEmail, String fromPassword,
             List<String> toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody) {
    this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
    this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
    this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
    this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
    this.emailBody = emailBody;

    emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
    Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");

}

public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
        MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));
    for (String toEmail : toEmailList) {
        Log.i("GMail","toEmail: "+toEmail);
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(toEmail));
    }

    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
    // emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email
    Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");
    return emailMessage;
}

public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
    Log.i("GMail","allrecipients: "+emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");
}

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.tsiw.testeinvite;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.enviar);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("SendMailActivity", "Send Button Clicked.");

            final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName()

            //RANDOM PASSWORD
            String output ="";
            char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".toCharArray();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                sb.append(c);
            }
            output = sb.toString();

            String fromEmail = "REMOVED";

            String fromPassword = "REMOVED";

            String toEmails = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();

            List toEmailList = Arrays.asList(toEmails
                    .split(","));

            Log.d("SendMailActivity", "To List: " + toEmailList);

            String emailSubject = "Bem-Vindo à GoGamification";

            String emailBody = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto))
                    .getText().toString();

            String textoB = emailBody +
                    "\n" +"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+
                    "Link para a Google Play Store: " + "\n" + "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<"+appPackageName+">"+
                    "\n" + "\n"+ "\n"+
                    "Credenciais: "+"\n"+
                    "Password: "+ output;

            new SendMailTask(MainActivity.this).execute(fromEmail, fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, textoB);
        }
    });
} 
}
```

**SendMailTask**

```
package com.tsiw.testeinvite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
private Activity sendMailActivity;

public SendMailTask(Activity activity) {
    sendMailActivity = activity;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);
    statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
    statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
    statusDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
    try {
        Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
        publishProgress("Processing input....");
        GMail androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                args[1].toString(), (List) args[2], args[3].toString(),
                args[4].toString());
        publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
        Log.d("SendMailTask", "Preparing mail message...");
        androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
        publishProgress("Sending email....");
        Log.d("SendMailTask", "Sending email...");
        androidEmail.sendEmail();
        publishProgress("Email Sent.");
        Log.d("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        publishProgress(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
        Log.d("SendMailTask", "Não enviou");
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
    statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());

}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    statusDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

Comment: Just a heads up you might want to remove the usernames and passwords for the GMail accounts that you use in your code. Definitely from StackOverflow, would probably be a good idea to look into a better way of doing it for your app also.

Comment: Also try port 587

Comment: it i put that port it gives me this error:
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to disable firewall or antivirus? also can you try to connect via different ports?

Here is the list of ports gmail is using.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en

Also i would advice to read this article to debug your email application.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug